# SF short story (Playboy-70's?) where a man with mental powers visits the President and is killed as he leaves

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to find this one for someone on another site.  The plot synopsis as we both remember it is that a man has mental powers probably controlling type, gets into see the President and as he is leaving he's whacked on the head with a hammer and killed. My additional memory is that someone says: "He never said he could read minds."

I also remember the artwork illustrating the story because I cut it out and used it on a collage.

[image: Story artwork showing eyes with "fire eye lashes"]

Pretty sure it was in Playboy but a search of published short story titles rang no bells.

Comment: https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-815956893-livro-mundo-sem-estrelas-poul-anderson-_JM - Those eyes are cropped from the cover of World Without Stars by Poul Anderson

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned that I did a Google image search and found that Portuguese cover, but World Without Stars is a novel, not a short story.  Probably just a case of the artist making two sales of the same piece.

Comment: Hmm, might have to browse all Playboys up till now... For erm... Research.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it. The story is called ["The Most Powerful Tailor in the World"](https://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-xpm-1996-10-24-9610240098-story.html) by Michael Crichton, published in *The Best of Playboy Fiction, Volume 1*

The burning eyes can be seen on the cover image below.

[image: Cover of "The Best of Playboy Fiction". It says MICHAEL CRICHTON in large letters, and then "The Most Powerful Tailor in the World" directly underneath. Below that is a pair of eyes with fire covering the eyelashes and extending upwards.]